# How to dynamically resize an image inside an email client?

Tags: html, image, email, email-client

Are there ways to resize an image to fit thew window the image is being viewed in *WITHOUT* javascript and limited CSS?

I ask because I have an email campaign that I send out that features a main image that I want as large as possible *without* scrolling. I have read ways to do this with javascript and jQuery but I do not see a way to do this that the majority of email clients will read and react to properly. Is this possible? And if so - How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you should be able to do it

---

```
    /****this is the Css****/
    .full {
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
     }
    /***end Css***/
   <!--Now the html--!>
   <section>
   <img src="image/main.png" class="full">
   </section>
```

Or you can go the simple way 
       
*update

### you can do it like this

```
    <img src="image/main.png" style="width:100%; height:auto; border:none;" />
```

and if they have an option to put it as html to do it like that as it should render correctly like that

Comment: I would have to do this using inline styles for email clients. But will that be read by the majority of email clients?

Comment: I have tried this and it has a few glitches it seems in email clients. Still working with it though if you have any thoughts.

Comment: @ Others who see this answer - This answer works in *some* email clients. Test before using.

Answer (score 13):

This is the correct way to do it for a html email:

```
<img alt="" src="" width="100%" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
```

It will auto resize to match the width of the container element (which should always be a `<td>`).

Note that on some clients (Outlook '07, '10 & '13 in particular), the image will not exceed it's maximum dimensions. If you are working with a max-width fluid template this will not be an issue providing your image width matches the max width.

Comment: This didn't work for me in outlook 2016. Image inside `<td>`. Instead of expected 110px width (width of the parent table cell) it becomes huge, probably 100%.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be as archaic as possible to make HTML emails work across all clients.

Inline styles and HTML 4 code should do the trick. Be warned though - max-width and max-height works in most clients, but this does NOT include Outlook 2007/2010/2013/365 which could well be over half of your target audience. Width works in all clients - but NOT on div and p tags in Outlook 2007/2010/2013/365! Always use tables not divs to be certain it will work.

Basically, always assume something isn't going to work and design for the smallest possible margin for error - and ALWAYS use inline styling or it might well get stripped.

If in doubt consult the oracle, I always do :)

Source: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/b/

Answer (score 0):

**HOW TO MAKE AN IMAGE RESIZE ITSELF IN A GMAIL**

First, here is the HTML code we will be working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Image Resizer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Point to your image by placing the path in the source (src) attribute. -->
    <img src="http://yourImagePathHere.jpg" style="width:100%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100%;" />
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: Notice the part that reads "http://yourImagePathHere.jpg". This is the path that points to the image you want resized in the GMail. Put the URL for your image here. In order to run this code
in a browser, you’ll need to have it saved as an HTML document. You can
accomplish this by copying and pasting the code above into a code editor or text
editor (such as Notepad on a PC or TextEdit on a MAC) and save it with the
extension “.html”.

If you are using TextEdit on a MAC, you will need to switch to plain text editing
before pasting the code. To do this, choose “Make Plain Text” from the “Format”
menu.

For this example, we will assume your file name is “**image_resizer.html**”. If you
need to change the image, you will need to edit the HTML document with a code
or text editor. To do this, right click the HTML document and choose “Open With”
and select a code editor or text editor. Then, swap out the image source path
(bolded in the example above), replacing it with the path that points to the
updated image. Then save, and your HTML file should ready to go and updated
to point to the new image.

If you are using TextEdit on a MAC, you will need to start a new document,
switch to plain text editing, paste the code again, and then change the path to the
image.

Step 1: Open **image_resizer.html** in a browser. To do this, double click it OR
right click it and select a browser from the “Open With” menu.

Step 2: Click anywhere on the webpage. You can click on the image itself or the
white space on the webpage. The idea here is to make sure that we will have
the pointer’s focus on the window to verify that the page is ready to be selected.

Step 3: Select All. Do this by using “Ctrl + A” on a PC … OR … “Command + A”
on a MAC. The page contents will be highlighted.

Step 4: Copy. Do this by using “Ctrl + C” on a PC … OR … “Command + C” on
a MAC. The page contents will be copied to the clipboard. (That just means that
the computer memorizes it).

Step 5: Now that the contents are copied to the clipboard (memorized by the
computer), open your Gmail and click the compose button. Place your curser in
the content area (click in the area where you type a message).

Step 6: Paste. Do this by using “Ctrl + V” on a PC … OR … “Command + V” on
a MAC.

Step 7. Finish typing your email message and send it.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with really big images without any kind of a container. I fixed it by using `max-width` to ensure the image wouldn't be too big.

```
    <img
        src=""
        width="100%"
        style="max-width: 80vw; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"
    />
```

Using both width and max-width ensures the image will take the full available space, but not too much. I used `80vw` and not `100` because people rarely read your emails in a fullscreen mode, usually more often using a viewer (Gmail), which usually uses a bit of the available space.